# how to add select box form validation

Tags: jquery, forms, validation

im using this form validation script on my site:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    // Place ID's of all required fields here.
    required = ["name", "email", "country", "message",];
    // If using an ID other than #email or #error then replace it here
    email = $("#email");
    errornotice = $("#error");
    // The text to show up within a field when it is incorrect
    emptyerror = "Please enter a value in field";
    emailerror = "Please enter a valid e-mail.";

    $("#theform").submit(function(){    
        //Validate required fields
        for (i=0;i<required.length;i++) {
            var input = $('#'+required[i]);
            if ((input.val() == "") || (input.val() == emptyerror)) {
                input.addClass("needsfilled");
                input.val(emptyerror);
                errornotice.fadeIn(750);
            } else {
                input.removeClass("needsfilled");
            }

        }
        // Validate the e-mail.
        if (!/^([a-zA-Z0-9_\.\-])+\@(([a-zA-Z0-9\-])+\.)+([a-zA-Z0-9]{2,4})+$/.test(email.val())) {
            email.addClass("needsfilled");
            email.val(emailerror);
        }

        //if any inputs on the page have the class 'needsfilled' the form will not submit
        if ($(":input").hasClass("needsfilled")) {
            return false;
        } else {
            errornotice.hide();
            return true;
        }
    });

    // Clears any fields in the form when the user clicks on them
    $(":input").focus(function(){       
       if ($(this).hasClass("needsfilled") ) {
            $(this).val("");
            $(this).removeClass("needsfilled");
       }
    });
});
```

the problem is that i dont have the code for a select box

can anyone give me the code for validating a select box?
my select box name and id is "country"
and if the selection stays on "country" i want an error notice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use selected option property

```
var country = $('#country option:selected').val();
```

for your code loop will like

```
for (i=0;i<required.length;i++) {
        var input = $('#'+required[i]);

        if(input.attr('id')== 'country' && $('#country option:selected').val() == "") {
            input.addClass("needsfilled");
            input.val(emptyerror);
            errornotice.fadeIn(750);

        }else if ((input.val() == "") || (input.val() == emptyerror)) {
            input.addClass("needsfilled");
            input.val(emptyerror);
            errornotice.fadeIn(750);
        } else {
            input.removeClass("needsfilled");
        }
```

Comment: actually i modified it and it worked: var country = $('#country option:selected').val();
   if(country == "")
   {
   $("#msg").html("Please select country");
   return false;
   }

Answer (score 0):

Try with

```
var cntry = $("#country").val();
if(empty(cntry))
{
     alert('Select a country');
     return false;
 }
```

Comment: no it didnt...maybe because if(empty should be if country is selected since the default option in my drop down box is not empty but rather "country"

Answer (score 0):

Are you searching like http://jsfiddle.net/X5r8r/1109/

```
<select id="ddlViewBy">
<option value=""></option>    
<option value="1">test1</option>
<option value="2">test2</option>
<option value="3">test3</option>
</select>

<button id="submit"> submit </button>

$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#submit").click(function(){
        var select_box_value = $("#ddlViewBy").val();
        if(select_box_value == ""){
            alert('select value')
        }else{
        alert('success')
        }
    });
});
```